# Docker containers exited frequently with the code exited with code 250

Tags: docker, containers

I am a newbie to docker and trying docker for a new application deployment. Till yesterday, it was working fine, but today onwards the container unexpectedly closed with the following message
`Exited (250) 2 minutes away`
On restarting it works fine for a new minutes and then the same things happening. I tried to Google, but no one has experienced the exit code 250.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: This could be a variety of things depending on: the full error message (if there's anything else), how you're building your container, your Dockerfile, how you're running your Docker image. Can you please post this information as well?

Comment: How are you starting the container?

Comment: @AvinashTripathy Using the command `sudo docker start CONTAINER ID`

Comment: Are you using docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Usually exit status 250 error message we will get when `No such file or directory`.

Try to find any directory that exists and now got deleted for some reason.
Try to down the container and start the container from the scratch. I think that may solve the problem.

Reference:
https://github.com/wise2c-devops/breeze/issues/10